# Join 3 tuples with string replacement

Tags: python, string, tuples

I've the 3 tuples like below:

```
prefix = ('display')
command = ('command1 <PARAM> detail','command2 <PARAM> verbose')
params = ('param 1,param2,param n','nextcom1,nextcom2,nectcom n')
```

I would like to create joined strings tuple which replaces every `<PARAM>` block with all the params from the params tuple so the output would look like below:

```
commands = ('display command1 param1 detail','display command1 param2 detail','display command1 param n detail','display command2 nextcom1 verbose','display command2 nextcom2 verbose','display command2 netcom n verbose')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generator expression like this -

```
commands = tuple(prefix + ' ' + x.replace('<PARAM>',y) for x , z in zip(command,params) for y in z.split(','))
>>> ('display command1 param 1 detail', 'display command1 param2 detail', 'display command1 param n detail', 'display command2 nextcom1 verbose', 'display command2 nextcom2 verbose', 'display command2 nectcom n verbose')
```